# find href values filtering by class with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have page source that has “a class” links like the example below.  I would like to return a list containing all the “href” values, so in the example below "/detail/Request-Technology%2C-LLC-Oakland-CA-94609/napil006/cyberMan”.  I’m using beautiful soup with find_all trying to use the ‘a class’ attribute, but it doesn’t return anything.  Can anyone see what I’m doing wrong and suggest a solution?

source:

```
<a class="web-btn-link easy-click" href="/detail/Request-Technology%2C-LLC-Oakland-CA-94609/napil006/cyberMan" id="position15" onclick="cookieJobID('b54b4b964def18552eefff31d034d2a5');handleBackButton(this);" style="font-size:18px;" title=“stuff” value="b54b4b964def18552eefff31d034d2a5">
```

Code:

```
BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source).find_all('href', {'a class':'web-btn-link easy-click'})
```

output:

```
[]
```

Comment: Do you have an url so we can try out different selectors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can collect all the desired elements through *BeautifulSoup* and store in a list and then iterate over the list to print the `href` attribute as follows:

```
href_elements = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source).find_all('a', {'class':'web-btn-link easy-click'})
for href_element in href_elements:
    print(href_element.href)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup elements do not have `href` attributes. What you are triggering instead is an implicit `.find('href')` by trying to access that attribute.

Comment: Next, BeautifulSoup parses class attributes out into a list; while you *can* match against the literal text still, you now won't match elements with *more* classes or listing the class in a different order.

Comment: Last but not least, your `find_all()` can return elements that don't *have* a `href` attribute, you may need to account for that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This answer being one of my initial attempts with BeautifulSoup I am sure moving forward your review comments will be priceless.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you, I combined your find_all argument with the previous posters solution and got a working solution.

Comment: @modLmakur what, if anything, was missing from my answer that needed combining? The `for` loop?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have explicitly asked OP to select your answer as the solution as it covers numerous aspects which will be immensely helpful to the future readers. Possiby being a _new contributor_ he misjudged to select the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your first mistake is to pass an attribute name to `find_all()`, which interprets the first argument as a *tagname* instead. Next, you are asking `find_all()` to filter the tags it finds to only return those that have a `a class` attribute that matches the given value, tags can't have attribute names with a space in it.

Note that you don't have `a class` tags here, you have `a` tags, with a `class` and `href` attribute. So you'd want to use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'web-btn-link', 'href': True})
```

The `'href': True` filter only matches if a tag has that attribute defined. Note that I filter on just *one* of the two classes; see [*Searching By CSS Class*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) why this matters, but you generally don't want to preclude matching tags with more than just those two classes you've found. In the vast majority of documents, you usually only need to match one of the classes (and `easy-click` sounds like a class for a script or CSS enhancement, applied to potentially different elements on the page).

This kind of search is much easier with a CSS [`.select()` call](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
tags = soup.select("a.web-btn-link.easy-click[href]")
```

This looks for `a` tags with at least *both* the `web-btn-link` and `easy-click` classes and only those that have an `href` attribute.

The call will still produce a sequence of tag objects, to get just the attributes, use subscription:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
tags = soup.select("a.web-btn-link[href]")
urls = [t['href'] for t in tags]
```

Or, just printing them one by one:

```
for tag in tags:
    print(t[‘href’])
```

Comment: @Martin Pieters thank you, this did the trick and thanks for the explanation.  I did modify your code slightly: soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'web-btn-link easy-click', 'href': True})
urls = [t['href'] for t in tags]

Comment: @modLmakur This answer seems to be more canonical than the other one. I would suggest to accept this answer as a solution so that the answer will benefit the future readers as well.